# Images appearing bigger than normal in IE

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an issue regarding the [website](http://www.greenninja.org) I am working on. The website images at the bottom of the home page appear fine in Firefox, Chrome etc. However in IE, the images are appearing bigger than the normal size. Could you suggest what could be the issue. I am not able to figure out the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In `bootstrap.min.css` there is a img property that says: `img { width: auto; }`.

To fix this issue in IE, you should avoid "width" tag in

`<img width="100">`

and use

`<img style="width: 100px" />`

instead which will override default style in `bootstrap.min.css` because IE doesn't recognize value without a measure (px)

Comment: +1. You should avoid using the old `width="100"` attributes and use `style` or separate CSS code anyway; this just makes it all the more important.